# Wrong Markdown rendering with Redcarpet and Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, ruby-on-rails-7, redcarpet

I'm using redcarpet gem with Ruby on Rails 7 to render Markdown as HTML. The problem is that is not rendering correctly the code blocks, it is rendering as:

```html
<code class="ruby">
  def func
    puts "Hello there"
  end
</code>
```

The correct output should be the above code without the code tags, and if I try to render different language the output is the same with the code tags.

The HTML rendered is the next:

```html
<pre>
  <code data-highlighted="yes" class="hljs language-ruby">
    "<code "
    <span class="hljs-keyword">class</span>
    "="
    <span class="hljs-string">"ruby"</span>
    "> "
    <span class="hljs-keyword">def</span>
    <span class="hljs-title function_">func</span>
    " puts "
    <span class="hljs-string">"Hello there"</span>
    <span class="hljs-keyword">end</span>
    " <"
    <span class="hljs-regexp">/code></span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Here is my code:

The function that renders the Markdown

```rb
def markdown(text)
    options = {
      no_links: false,
      hard_wrap: true,
      link_attributes: { target: "_blank" }
    }
    extensions = {
      hard_wrap: true,
      autolink: true,
      no_intra_emphasis: true,
      tables: true,
      fenced_code_blocks: true,
      strikethrough: true,
      lax_spacing: true,
      space_after_headers: true,
      quote: true,
      footnotes: true,
      highlight: true,
      underline: true
    }
    renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
    Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions).render(text).html_safe
end
```

The code where I call the markdown function:

```html
<p class="break-words line-clamp-3"><%= markdown(post.body) %></p>
```

post.body contains all the Markdown text, for this example the text that sent to the markdown mehtod is:

Output of post.body is

````bash
irb(main):005> Post.find(86).body
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 86], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "```ruby\r\n\r\ndef func\r\n  puts \"Hello there\"\r\nend\r\n\r\n```"
irb(main):006>
````

In the form to create a new post I have a text area and I'm allowing this field in the params method, I believe this is not the problem. Anyone who face to this problem already and can help me to solve this error please?

Comment: You forgot to show the markdown text that's being converted.

Comment: Yes, the code tags must exists and exists, but should not be rendered literally, only the code inside the code tags. I already update the post with the rendered  HTML

Comment: post.body is only the parameter sent to the markdown method, post.body contains all the markdown text and the markdown method should returns the markdown text converted to html code. post is an instance of a Post, like post = Post.first, and the body is a field of the Post model

Comment: Sure, I'm showing the ouput in the console of text. that is the parameter of markdown method, that comes from post.body

Comment: Sorry, I already update the post with the output directly from the irb console with your example

Comment: Unfortunately I unable to assist any further as this appears to be caused by something outside the code you posted. Using exactly what is available here my [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/UntimelyPapayawhipScript#main.rb) works as expected.

Comment: Sure, I don't know why the html rendered prints the code tags, anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: Okay I figured out why but I am not certain how to resolve it. You are processing the markdown to HTML and then running that output through highlight.js which results in exactly what you are showing. You would probably be better off using a different highlighter like `rouge` that can be integrated into RedCarpet.

Comment: ooooh that's the problem, previously I had been using action text instead of redcarpet, and i was using highlight.js to highlight sintax, I commented the code for highlight and now it's working. It seems that the output of this new gem (redcarpet) is not the same as the action text output and the code for highlight sintax doesn't work anymore.

Comment: In short, the problem was JavaScript code to highlight the sintax with highlight.js library. Now it works as expected. Thank you so much for your suport!! @engineersmnky

Comment: I can still using highlight.js, but I have to change code to match it with the new output

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are rendering the Markdown to HTML and then passing all of that through highlight.js which results in your output.

Simplest solution and keep syntax highlighting is to override the way Red Carpet generates code blocks

For Example

```
class CustomRender < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def block_code(code,language)
    code
  end
end
```

And then just replace this `renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)` with `renderer = CustomRender.new(options)`.

[Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/UntimelyPapayawhipScript#main.rb)